# React suspense fallback glitch on prefetched component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to do code splitting and prefetching, here is what i do with my routes

```js
const UploadVerificationPage = lazy(() =>
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "verification" */
    /* webpackPrefetch: true */
    "src/scenes/Verification/pages/UploadVerificationPage"
  )
);
```

the bundle is separated to verification chunk, and it adds `<link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/verification.66e056e5.chunk.js">`
but i have problem with suspense. in my index.js
i have this code

```js
const App = (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HelmetProvider>
        <WebRouter />
      </HelmetProvider>
    </Provider>
  </Suspense>
);
```

this make whenever I go into that page (UploadVerificationPage) I got a glitch of the `Loading` component fallback before enter the page. is it expected or any solution to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Have you find any solution? I got this too